# git format-patch X..Y for a specific author

Tags: git, patch

I was wondering if you can generate patches for a range but only limit to commits from a specific author, the way you do with `git log --author='bob'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

According to [reference](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) on `git format-patch` it accepts `<revision range>`

> Generic  expression (see "SPECIFYING REVISIONS"
>   section in gitrevisions(7)) means the commits in the specified range.

Details may be found in the [reference](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) but we only need this one:

> ^!, e.g. HEAD^!
>
> A suffix ^ followed by an exclamation mark is the same as giving commit  and then all its parents prefixed with ^ to exclude them
>   (and their ancestors).

So you'll need:

```
git log X..Y --author='<AUTHOR>' --format="%H" | sed 's/$/^!/g' | xargs -I{} git format-patch {}
```

`git log X..Y --author='<AUTHOR>' --format="%H"` produces output in format of 40-digit sha1 sums.

`sed 's/$/^!/g'` adds ^! at the end of each line

`xargs -I{} git format-patch {}` just runs `git format-patch` with each line

Comment: This works great, the only mild issue is that it breaks the increment number in the patch naming (ie they're all prefixed with `0001` for some reason), but that's not a big deal in my case. Thanks!

Comment: This modified command will help provide an incremented number: `git log --author='<AUTHOR>' --format="%H" --reverse | sed 's/$/^!/g' | nl -w 1 -s ' ' | xargs -I{} sh -c "git format-patch --start-number {}"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the modified solution proposed by [jdknight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693291/jdknight) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891595/git-format-patch-x-y-for-a-specific-author#comment75931483_28893599) involves `--reverse`.

```bash
git log --author='<AUTHOR>' --format="%H" --reverse | \
  sed 's/$/^!/g' | nl -w 1 -s ' ' | \
  xargs -I{} sh -c "git format-patch --start-number {}"
```

That is an order issue, highlighted with With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b988427918c767fc7782a387c9c8de9e147b983d/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> rev^!" did not show combined diff to go to the rev from its parents.

See [commit a79c6b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a79c6b60817c74534815bf132f0b26aa8e325874), [commit 9f91da7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f91da752fa28e405e91dfd6bd7372f897bbae8d), [commit 793c211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/793c21182e34f109b4f438944b4272fb50862ad5) (01 Oct 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b988427](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b988427918c767fc7782a387c9c8de9e147b983d), 25 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`revisions.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f91da752fa28e405e91dfd6bd7372f897bbae8d): unspecify order of resolved parts of `^!`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> gitrevisions(7) says that `<rev>^!` resolves to `<rev>` and then all the parents of `<rev>`.
> [`revision.c::handle_revision_arg_1()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9f91da752fa28e405e91dfd6bd7372f897bbae8d/revision.c#L2073) actually adds all parents first, *then* `<rev>`.
> Change the documentation to leave the order unspecified, to avoid misleading readers.

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9f91da752fa28e405e91dfd6bd7372f897bbae8d/Documentation/revisions.txt#L366):

> ### `<rev>^!`, e.g. `HEAD^!`:
>
> A suffix '`^`' followed by an exclamation mark is the same as giving commit '`<rev>`' and all its parents prefixed with '`^`' to exclude them (and their ancestors).