# Extract code written by a specific author

Tags: git

I want to do a pretty simple thing - extract entire code (while keeping the original file structure) i (or anyone else) wrote in a given timeframe from my git repository.

The code is not supposed to be working or make sense, i just need to do this because my employer requires me to send him a "snapshots" of what i've done each month in cause of any governmental control.

Is that possible? I've been searching for it but can't really find anything.

Comment: What you are looking for is basically a `diff` between two dates or two commits. Right?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891595/git-format-patch-x-y-for-a-specific-author

Comment: yes @JRR , that's one option. I would prefer it to be "non-dev person friendly" so the actual code would be better but i can live with the diffs if there is no other option.

Comment: Does this threat answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509419/git-diff-with-author-filter

Comment: Thanks for random -1, good job with constructive criticism. @JRR yes i think i can live with that ;) Feel free to copy-paste the answer with a back-link as an answer and i'm gonna accept it. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, copy-pasting answers from other posts is [explicitly forbidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160072/191410). That's considered plagiarism. If the answer to another question seems to perfectly answer your question, you should vote to close your question as a duplicate of the other. You should never, never, never copy-paste an answer verbatim, just so that it can be "accepted". (Copying portions of another answer, with attribution, for the purpose of reference is fine, but outright copying is going to get you in trouble.)

Comment: actually that's exactly what i was trying to say @JDB, i just articulated it wrong :)